# angularjs controller reload on model change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I created a bootstrap dropdown using angularjs. The code is given below

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    {{column}} <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li ng-repeat='col in columns'>
        <a href="#/view1#" ng-click="$parent.column = col">{{col}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

On clicking the model column changes but then the whole controller reloads and I am back to square one. Please help. I dont understand whats happening. Why is the controller reloading?

Comment: Remove the href part, because not only does the model change, but the whole page refreshes.

Comment: what a silly mistake. I dint notice that and have been breaking my head for so long. Thanks a lot for your quick response. answer the question and ill accept it.

Comment: It happens. Sometimes href is kept for what's inside it, yet the redirection is prevented by returning false from the click listener. I assumed that's not the case here.

Comment: No its not. It isnt supposed to be there at all. I had copied it from another file and started changing. So missed out removing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `href` part (or prevent redirection from the click listener), because not only does the model change, but the whole page refreshes. It's in:

```
<a href="#/view1#" ng-click="$parent.column = col">{{col}}</a>
```